# @angular/fire Realtime Database + Ionic How to print console.log list observable

Tags: angular, firebase, ionic-framework, firebase-realtime-database, angularfire2

### Background

I am using ionic 4, "@angular/fire": "^5.0.2", "rxjs": "^6.3.3", "rxjs-compat": "^6.3.3".

### Question

**How to print console.log a list observable from Firebase?** Include the keys and values. I am expecting an array of JSON format.

I am able to read the database, however I cannot see it in console.log. I actually want to use the values I retrieved from Firebase list observable for another funnction, but because I cannot see the values in console.log I don't know its behavior.

### The Code

This is my Firebase node I want to get values from
[image: Firebase node]

This is my **home.ts**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { IonicPage, NavController, NavParams, ToastController } from 'ionic-angular';

import { AngularFireAuth } from '@angular/fire/auth';
import { AngularFireDatabase, AngularFireList } from '@angular/fire/database';
import { UserProfile } from './../../models/user-profile';
import { RestoProfile } from './../../models/resto-profile';

import { OrderMenuPage } from '../order-menu/order-menu';


@IonicPage()
@Component({
  selector: 'page-home',
  templateUrl: 'home.html'
})
export class HomePage {
  restoProfileData: AngularFireList<RestoProfile[]>;
  restoProfileRef: AngularFireList<RestoProfile[]>;

  constructor(private afAuth: AngularFireAuth, private afDatabase: AngularFireDatabase,
    private toast: ToastController,
    public navCtrl: NavController, public navParams: NavParams) {
  }

  ionViewDidLoad() {
    this.afAuth.authState.subscribe(data => {
      if(data && data.email && data.uid){
        this.toast.create({
          message: `Welcome to brianApp-customer, ${data.email}`,
          duration: 3000
        }).present();

        this.restoProfileRef = this.afDatabase.list<RestoProfile>(`profile/`);
        this.restoProfileData = this.restoProfileRef.snapshotChanges();

      }
      else {
        this.toast.create({
          message: `Could not find authentication details`,
          duration: 3000
        }).present();
      }
    });
  }
```

This is my **home.html**

```
<ion-header>
  <ion-navbar>
    <button ion-button menuToggle>
      <ion-icon name="menu"></ion-icon>
    </button>
    <ion-title>
      Ionic Blank
    </ion-title>
  </ion-navbar>
</ion-header>

<ion-content padding>
  Choose a restaurant?
<ion-list>
  <ion-item *ngFor="let data of restoProfileData | async" (click)="selectResto(data)">
    <h2>Key: {{ data.payload.key }}</h2>
    <h2>Location: {{data.payload.val().location}}</h2>
    <h2>ownerName: {{data.payload.val().ownerName}}</h2>
    <h2>restoName: {{data.payload.val().restoName}}</h2>
  </ion-item>
</ion-list>
</ion-content>
```

I tried `console.log(this.restoProfileData);` but the console returns me [image: console.log]

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

snapshotchanges() will return

```
Observable<AngularFireAction<DataSnapshot>[]>
```

for collections. In order to subscribe and show the content inside, you can:

```
 this.restoProfileData = this.restoProfileRef
    .snapshotChanges()
    .map(changes => {
      return changes.map(change => ({key: change.payload.key, ...change.payload.val()}));
    })
```

Comment: Thanks for replying. Where to put this line of code? I put it here: `this.restoProfileData = this.restoProfileRef.snapshotChanges().map(actions =>
          actions.map(a => ({ key: a.key, ...a.payload.val() }))
        )` but it throws an error: `this.restoProfileRef.snapshotChanges(...).map is not a function`

Comment: You need to use pipe()

Comment: Hi @SureshKumarAriya can you please give a more detailed example, how to use the pipe()

Comment: @Joe Wu. Following your latest edit, I got this: `this.restoProfileRef.snapshotChanges(...).map is not a function`

Comment: you could try Suresh's approach by using pipe() function. I guess map hasn't been imported properly in your component.

Answer (score 1):

You can use 'tap' operator for console.log() in rxjs.

```
this.restoProfileData = this.restoProfileRef.snapshotChanges().pipe(
   tap((data)=> console.log(data))
);
```

or

```
this.restoProfileData = this.restoProfileRef
    .snapshotChanges()
    .pipe(
      map(changes => ({
      changes.map(change => ({key: change.payload.key, ...change.payload.val()}));
      })),
      tap((data)=> console.log(data))
    )
```

Comment: The first option. You need `import { tap } from 'rxjs/operators';`. However I still get an abstract metadata values in console.log. I only want the values I see in firebase to be logged.

Comment: try option 2 and let me know

Comment: The second option, you need to add `);` at the end of the code. But this time I got another error: `Runtime Error map is not defined`

Comment: did you import map operator added ')'. try now

Comment: Sorry. Now I added `import { map } from 'rxjs/operators';` But now the browser and console do not show anything....

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/181836/discussion-between-brian-ivander-t-p-and-suresh-kumar-ariya).